# How to get text from a div span in soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to get the text within a span from beautiful soup however it doesn't return the 631.
I want to get the 631 from this html.

```
<div class="jsx-3024393758 jsx-3850983025 sold">
  <img alt="sold" src="data:imagesd">
  <span class="jsx-3024393758 jsx-3850983025">
    <span class="jsx-3024393758 jsx-3850983025 sold-text">Sold</span> "631"</span>
</div>
```

My code right now is like this.

```
sold = soup.select_one('jsx-3024393758 jsx-3850983025 sold-text','.jsx-3024393758 jsx-3850983025 sold').get('style', '').replace('width:','').text
```

However it returns null
Please do help, and if a little explanation of where I went wrong would be very helpful.

Comment: That HTML has invalid syntax -- there's one opening `<span>` but two closing `</span>`s.

Comment: hi you're right, missed out a span, fix the span already, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code and it seems to be a wild mix of things that do not focus your issue. So concerning your question take a minute or two to read [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to get an idea of chaining selectors.

---

In this specific case I would select the `<div>` and extract pick the last element from `stripped_strings`:

```
list(soup.select_one('div.sold').stripped_strings)[-1]
```

###### Example

```
html = '''
<div class="jsx-3024393758 jsx-3850983025 sold">
  <img alt="sold" src="data:imagesd">
  <span class="jsx-3024393758 jsx-3850983025">
    <span class="jsx-3024393758 jsx-3850983025 sold-text">Sold</span> "631"</span>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

list(soup.select_one('div.sold').stripped_strings)[-1]
```

Comment: that works like a charm. ok so this is much easier to understand. you get the div that contains sold and get the last item in the list. thank you